# Discord.js message.react is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a discord bot set up that does reaction roles. I use IDs to cache the messages that need to have reactions. I make the bot first react with the according emojis before it handles them. This is what caching the messages looks like:

```js
  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(info.GUILD_ID)
  const channel1 = guild.channels.cache.get(info.MAINROLES_CHANNEL_ID)
  const message1 = await channel1.messages.fetch(info.MAINROLES_MESSAGE_ID)
  const channel2 = guild.channels.cache.get(info.HELPERROLES_CHANNEL_ID)
  const message2 = await channel2.messages.fetch(info.HELPERROLES_MESSAGE_ID)
  const channel3 = guild.channels.cache.get(info.VERIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
  const message3 = await channel3.messages.fetch(info.VERIFICATION_MESSAGE_ID)
```

The problem I have is with message 2. When doing `message1.react("")` everything works fine. However, when I do `message2.react("")` I get an error. I see no reason for the error to be thrown as I get both messages the exact same way. Does this have to do with discord bot permissions? Or is it something else that I'm doing wrong?

This is the error:

```
(node:4102) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message2.react is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/denesgarda/Documents/GitHub/cmd/bot/index.js:47:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:4102) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4102) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Are you sure `message2` isn't null/undefined?

Comment: @futur Yes, I'm sure. That was my first thought too

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet but I will try to help you. So I think that the message1 and message2 are stuck because they are entered in the same time.
I am not sure but you can try to make it like this

```
 const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(info.GUILD_ID)
  const channel1 = guild.channels.cache.get(info.MAINROLES_CHANNEL_ID)
  const message1 = await channel1.messages.fetch(info.MAINROLES_MESSAGE_ID)
    message1.react(emoji);
  const channel2 = guild.channels.cache.get(info.HELPERROLES_CHANNEL_ID)
  const message2 = await channel2.messages.fetch(info.HELPERROLES_MESSAGE_ID)
    message2.react(emoji);
  const channel3 = guild.channels.cache.get(info.VERIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
  const message3 = await channel3.messages.fetch(info.VERIFICATION_MESSAGE_ID)
    message3.react(emoji);
```

If that doesn't work maybe try to get the id using `const channel = bot.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === 'channelid');` this function